# Library subprocess throws Windows Error "not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, subprocess

Hence I was writing this py program.

```
import subprocess
string="ihateminority.py"
process=subprocess.Popen(string,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res=process.communicate("3 5")
print res[0]
```

And I got this Window Error.

[image]

Obviously, the error came from the library, not me. Is there anyway to fix this, or just simply avoid id. (I cant use external library)

Answer (score 0):

That's because "ihateminority.py" is not a valid Win32 application.  You should call "python.exe" and pass it "ihateminority.py" as an argument.